# CSS Transitions on menu items not working

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

it's the first time I'm using css transitions/transformations and it's not working out that well.
I'm simply trying to translate from bottom to position each entry of a toggled menu, but I'm getting strange results.
When I run the code within my app it executes the transition only on the first item of the list instead of all items.
When I run the same code from jsfiddle the transition doesn't work at all on any item.

Please see my jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/irith/874f9q6h/37/)

I've looked at the documentation, at so many different examples and at many other solutions for similar issues. I've tried them all, defying height, removing display, but nothing seems to make any difference

```html
<header>
  <a id="menu">
    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</header>

<nav class="nav nav-sm">
  <ul class="nav__list">
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
    <li class="nav__item"><a href="#">WORKS</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;

  background-color: #68c7c1;
  min-height: 56px;
  transition: min-height 0.3s;
}
header #menu {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:10px;
  color: #eceeef;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #68c7c1;
}
.nav-sm, .nav-lg { display: none; }
.nav-sm.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100% - 56px);
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.nav__list, .nav__item { width: 100%; }
.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.nav__item {
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav__item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #eceeef;
}
.nav-sm .nav__list .nav__item {
  color: red;
  transition: -transform 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 3s ease-in-out;
}
.nav-sm.open .nav__item {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  font-size: 2em;
  transform: translate(0,-50px);
  -moz-transform: translate(0,-50px);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50px);
}
```

An example of what I'm trying to achieve is something similar to the menu of [this](http://kurtwinterdesign.com/) portfolio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you exactly trying to do ? animation ? transition when clicked ?

here is an example of how to write animation via css :

```
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}
```

Comment: I was thinking to use transitions purely because I didn't know of the existence of animation... I'm trying to achieve the effect that you can see in the menu of the portfolio I've linked above ..so when the menu is open, the menu entries slide in from the bottom one by one...

Comment: I suggest using animation via css and just keep the state of it in the end with `animation: example 1.0s forwards;`

Comment: or you can use javascript animation( less recommended) - here is an example https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_animate.asp

Comment: I'll try with CSS animation and I'll let you know...I'm won't use js as I'm trying to get closer to CSS :)

Comment: cool , please mark this answer as right if you feel liked it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

The way they did it in the example you provided is with js with some animation library, if you'd inspect their code you can see it happening.

To achieve this animation we'll have to make use of the delay property either way using animation or transition and you will have to add a delay on every item, so when you add a new item to the menu you'll have to add a delay to that item, we can automate this using `js`

Here's a demo using transition, the [`timing function`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-timing-function.asp), delay and the duration will need extra care, i'll leave that you to adjust to your desired end result.

```js
var menu = document.querySelector("#menu");
var nav = document.querySelector(".nav-sm");

function openMenu(e) {
  nav.classList.toggle("open");
  e.stopPropagation();
};

function closeMenu(e) {
  nav.classList.remove("open");
};

menu.addEventListener("click", openMenu);
```

```css
#menu {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
}

li {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(5px);
  margin: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 30px;
  background: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
}

.open li:nth-child(1) {
  transition: all .4s linear;
}

.open li:nth-child(2) {
  transition: all .4s .2s linear;
}

.open li:nth-child(3) {
  transition: all .4s .4s linear;
}

.open li {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css">
<div id="menu">
  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
</div>



<ul class="nav-sm">
  <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">WORKS</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Zohir, thank you for your suggestion! I couldn't use transitions as I need to use display:none on the parent element and that seems to affect transitions so I'm using animations instead, but I have applied your suggestion about the delay on each list element and that worked out pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

So, I managed to achieve what I wanted by mixing both suggestions :)
Please see the result in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/irith/874f9q6h/104/).

The reason why the transition wasn't working it's because I'm using display:none on the .nav. This problem is resolved by using animation instead and applying a delay on each list element.

Thank you for both answers!

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: right;

  background-color: #68c7c1;
  min-height: 56px;
  transition: min-height 0.3s;
}
header #menu {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right:10px;
  color: #eceeef;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #68c7c1;
}
.nav-sm, .nav-lg { display: none; }
.nav-sm.open {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  height: calc(100% - 56px);
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.nav__list, .nav__item { width: 100%; }
.nav__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.nav__item {
  height:50px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
.nav__item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  color: #eceeef;
}

.nav-sm.open {
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .3s linear;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .3s linear;
}
.nav-sm.open .nav__item{
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

.nav-sm.open .nav__item:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .3s .1s linear;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .3s .1s linear;
}

.nav-sm.open .nav__item:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .3s .2s linear;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .3s .2s linear;
}

.nav-sm.open .nav__item:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-animation: slide-down .3s .3s linear;
  -moz-animation: slide-down .3s .3s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slide-down {
      0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-100%); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes slide-down {
      0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: translateY(-100%); }   
    100% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: translateY(0%); }
}
```